# How to enforce rules on Revision/Differential to change status if condition is satisfied?

Tags: phabricator

I want to configure Phabricator with some customized rules. I am very new to this tool and would appreciate some help or pointers to how to do it.

I want to make sure all reviewers in Revision/Differential should accept all changes before changing a state of the Revision. Once all reviewers accept it then change status of the Revision to Accepted/ready to land.

Currently in my case, I have a revision in which there are different files which need to be reviewed by different reviewers. I expect that, after all reviewers accept these changes only then change status of the Revision to accepted otherwise it should be stayed on status "Needs Review". But, whenever any one of the reviewer from list accept the changes, status of the Revision changes to "Accepted"/"ready to land".

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported. You can find discussion of this feature in the upstream, here:

https://secure.phabricator.com/T731

If some of the reviewers are really groups of people (for example, you want to make sure someone who is experienced with Python reviews all Python code, similar to "readability" at Google), you can create a project called "Python Reviewers" and add all the users who are experienced enough to do these reviews to the project. Then write a Herald rule to trigger a "blocking review" by the project whenever a change touches Python source. This will require all Python changes to be reviewed by someone from the project before they are "Accepted".

If your use case is more like "I want alincoln to look at the .c files and htaft to look at the .js files", but no reviewer will be examining the change as a whole, we philosophically discourage this. The most important feedback from code review -- by far -- is high-level feedback about the change as a whole, not feedback about implementation details. We encourage you to try to structure code review so that there is one clear author and one primary reviewer, each of whom are thinking about the entire change in the context of the surrounding software system.